# ASN.1: Can the SIZE constraint be used to constrain SEQUENCE (not SEQUENCE OF)

Tags: constraints, sequence, asn.1, subtype

Is the following type definition valid ASN.1 syntax?

```
MyType ::= SEQUENCE SIZE(2) {
  theID        OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
  someNumber   INTEGER OPTIONAL,
  someString   PrintableString OPTIONAL
}
```

I want to formally constrain the sequence such that for each instantiation exactly one of both optional attributes must be present.

PS: As `SEQUENCE` and `SEQUENCE OF` are encoded exactly the same way, I have the slight hope that this syntax is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is not valid. `SEQUENCE` is like a struct type with fields, where each field can be of different type. `SEQUENCE OF` is like an array, where all nested types are of same type. Thus, in `SEQUENCE OF` you can set constraint to array size. Same rules apply to `SET` and `SET OF`, just unordered.

I would solve your problem this way: create a `CHOICE` of all your optional fields (without `OPTIONAL` modifier) and add this CHOICE to your main type:

```
MyChoice ::= CHOICE {
  someNumber   INTEGER,
  someString   PrintableString
}

MyType ::= SEQUENCE {
  theID        OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
  myChoice  <  MyChoice
}
```

In this case, `theID` field is mandatory and exactly one of `MyChoice` elements is required.